# Getting specific post category in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I must get post if my category == academic (SelectField choice). But it doesn't work (posts are not **shown**). How can I get post data or form data for this?

I've tried

```
@categories.route("/category/academic")
def academic():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(
        Post.date_posted.desc()).filter(
        Post.category == "Academic").paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('academic.html', posts=posts)
```

and

```
@categories.route("/category/academic")
def academic():
    form = PostForm()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    post = Post(title=form.title.data,
                content=form.content.data,
                category=form.category.data)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(
        Post.date_posted.desc()).order_by(
        post.category == "Academic").paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('academic.html', posts=posts)
```

and

```
@categories.route("/category/academic")
def academic():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(
        Post.date_posted.desc()).filter(
        **PostForm**.category == "Academic").paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('academic.html', posts=posts)
```

### Post.category

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                            default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.String(50))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

### PostForm.category

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    category = SelectField('Category', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[(
        'Academic', 'Academic'), ('Art', 'Art')])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

### Template (category.html)## This template for posts - Showing the category.html - All of template

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} {% block content %} {% for post in posts.items %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <img
    class="rounded-circle article-img"
    src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.author.image_file) }}"
  />
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a
        class="mr-2"
        href="{{ url_for('users.user_posts', username=post.author.username) }}"
        >{{ post.author.username }}</a
      >
      <small class="text-muted">{{
        post.date_posted.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      }}</small>
      <small class="article-category">
        <mark
          ><a
            class="mr-2"
            href="{{ url_for('categories.category_route', category=post.category) }}"
            >{{ post.category }}</a
          ></mark
        >
      </small>
    </div>
    <h2>
      <a
        class="article-title"
        href="{{ url_for('posts.post', post_id=post.id) }}"
        >{{ post.title }}</a
      >
    </h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %} {% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1,
left_current=1, right_current=2) %} {% if page_num %} {% if posts.page ==
page_num %}
<a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('main.home', page=page_num) }}">{{
  page_num
}}</a>
{% else %}
<a
  class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"
  href="{{ url_for('main.home', page=page_num) }}"
  >{{ page_num }}</a
>
{% endif %} {% else %} ... {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

Doesn't work because posts are not **shown**.

Comment: please also show code of the template. What happens if you do this:     posts = Post.query.filter(
        Post.category == 'Academic').all() and then for post in posts: print (post). If category 'Academic' is somewhere in db, it should print something.

Comment: @gittert Hi, I've edited and I added code. Your code `posts = Post.query.filter( Post.category == 'Academic').all() ` prints, but now says **'list' object has no attribute 'paginate'**.

Comment: Great, one step at a time. We've now established that there is at least one result in your query. The error is probably from jinja about the missing pagination. Now instead of all(), type your original paginate(....) And test again. Please also add the complete error trail if that shows up.

Comment: @gittert Hi again, but it does not show any problems. Could there be a problem with template?

Comment: Yes, well there are some parts that I dont understand, like post.author.username. i dont see that attribute in the model. Let me try later today with a simplified test case and I'll come back on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works fine here. I copied your model, and parts of your template, which I further simplified for testing purposes. It works all just fine and results in your browser adapt nicely to the nr of items per page. In example below it is set on 2, but it works with 5 as well. Bear in mind you can only use attributes that are covered in the model and your query. Currently you have multiple issues on that. I suspect that your template is causing that you don't see any results.

python code:

```
page = request.args.get('page', 1, type = int)
posts = Post.query.filter_by(category = 'Academic').paginate(page=page, per_page=2)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts.items %}
    <a href="" > {{ post.title }} </a>
    <a href=""> {{ post.category }} </a>
    <p> {{ post.content }} </p>
{% endfor %}

{% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}

    {% if page_num %}
        {% if posts.page == page_num %}
            <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('home.home', page = page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('home.home', page = page_num) }}"> {{ page_num }} </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```